# Is there any way to solve docker compose load module error

Tags: docker-compose, redis, node-redis

result of docker-compose up in terminal:

```
cache
| 1:M 23 Mar 2023 17:19:09.783 # Module /data/modules/rejson.so failed to load: It does not have execute permissions.
cache
1 1:M 23 Mar 2023 17:19:09.783 # Can't load module from /data/modules/rejson.so: server aborting
```

EDIT:
For use redis json, I must copy rejson.so to docker. I think problem is in the volume or docker config on my server
here is the my if its important
docker-compose.yml:

```
version : "3"

services:
  cache:
    container_name: "cache"
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "6379"
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --loadmodule /data/modules/rejson.so --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass ${REDIS_PASS}
    volumes: 
      - cache:/data
      - ./dockerModules/rejson.so:/data/modules/rejson.so
    networks:
      - esdemate-network
  node:
   container_name: "node"
   image: nodejs
   environment:
     NODE_ENV: docker
   build: .
   ports:
     - "4000:4000"
   restart: always
   depends_on:
     - cache
   networks:
     - esdemate-network
  # db:
  #   container_name: "db"
  #   image: library/postgres:15
  #   restart: always
  #   environment:
  #     - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
  #     - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
  #     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  #   expose:
  #     - "5432"
  #   ports:
  #     - "5432:5432"
  #   volumes:
  #     - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  #     - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  #   networks:
  #     - esdemate-network

networks:
  esdemate-network:

volumes:
  cache:
      driver: local
  db-data:
```

how can i solve this permission error?
any idea?

i want to use redis on my server with redis json but this happening.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75826196/edit) the question and include your `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing special about "your Redis" you can just use a pre-built Redis Stack Docker image - this comes with JSON, Search and some other capabilities.  Example Docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redisstack
    image: "redis/redis-stack:latest"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
      - 8001:8001
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

The above also comes with RedisInsight, the visual tool for inspecting data in Redis.  That's exposed on port 8001.  If you don't want that, just don't expose that port or use the Redis Stack Server image instead as this doesn't have the RedisInsight tool built in:

https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack-server/tags

If you need to compile RedisJSON yourself and put it into some Redis image, then make sure that the `.so` file for RedisJSON has permissions set so that it can be read and executed by whichever user/group the `redis-server` process is running as in your container.  Also make sure that the location of the `.so` file matches where you tell `redis-server` to find it.  e.g. when starting redis-server you'd use `--loadmodule /path/to/redisjson.so` or add appropriate `loadmodule` directive to your `redis.conf` file.